# Extract non-numeric characters from string

Tags: c

I want to extract all the non-numeric characters from string. for example if we have
`p="22.5+31*6-6"`
I want to extract `+` , `*` and `-` respectively.

Comment: ...start programming. It's not that difficult. Use `isdigit(c)` to check if it is numeric, so if not, it must be non-numeric.

Comment: well i know but the problem is on the floating point....it is a non-numeric..

Comment: Do you expect anything other then ` + * / - = < > ( )` in the text?
may be it will be easier to to extract what you wont, instead of thinking how to remove the rest.

Comment: @Elias.123 If tthere is a problem with floating numbers when why did you mark the answer as the best that entirely ignores floating  numbers?

Comment: actually my main objective is to let the user enter a string by keyboard , then I want to extract the numbers and store them into an array (which I already did ) then extract the symbols and store them in another array... so I can use them separately.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow actually the answer is what i was look for..the rest i will do it my self.

Comment: "I want to extract the numbers ..." Ehm.. sounds like the wrong way to parse an expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `for` loop to traverse through the `string` and check whether current character is within the range of numeric characters. Sample code snippet for your reference.

```
     char p[] = "22.5+31*6-6";
     int loop;
     for(loop = 0; loop < strlen(p); loop++)
     {
        if(p[loop] < '0' || p[loop] > '9')
            printf("%c",p[loop]);               // printing the non numeric characters
     }
```

Comment: thank you , I don't know why I didn't think of that.

Comment: @Olaf: I just wanted to show the other way round what `isdigit` is processing, so that it will be easy to understand

Comment: Ok, but it is better to show how to do it correctly (it only works for digits, but not for e.g. letters due to no sequential placement in character set, localozation). Sidenote: `isdigit` evaluates the input only once. Not relevant here, but it allows for e.g.  `isdigit(p[loop++])`